# php: Calling Static Classes through a variable

Tags: php

Is there a way to call Static Classes / Methods by name?

Example:

```
$name = 'StaticClass';
($name)::foo();
```

I have classes which I keep all static methods in and I'd like to call them this way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$name::foo()
```

is possible since PHP5.3. In earlier versions you have to use

```
call_user_func(array($classname,$methodname))
```

Comment: @KoolKabin: pass arguments as further arguments to `call_user_func`. There's also `call_user_func_array`. See php.net.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this using the [call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func) function

it would look something like the following

```
$name = 'staticClass';
call_user_func(array($name, 'foo'));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of stuff I'm looking for. Though I hoped it would be easier.